# django-admin inline models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to django and I'm trying to create an app which uses an existing database (so changing the database isn't possible).

I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  person_identity = models.OneToOneField("Identity", primary_key=True)
  login           = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
  name            = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)

class Identity(models.Model):
  # auto generated ID-field DB: id bigint(20) PK, UI, AI, NN
  last_used = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  blocked   = models.IntegerField()

class IdentityAccessToken(models.Model):
    identity      = models.ForeignKey("Identity")
    accesstoken   = models.ForeignKey("AccessToken")
    cycle         = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class AccessToken(models.Model):
  id          = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  token       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
```

I have set up admin for my person-model and I want to show an inline which contains the accesstokens of the shown person.  As the person has an identity-model as well as a PK but the accesstokens refer to that identity I do not know how to handle that.

Is there a best practice to do such things?

Comment: FTR: nested inlines should be in Django 1.5 [#9025 (accepted, has patch)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9025).